# How to fetch data all (Just Like name, Father, Mother, Own name) data in single query by multple table in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables. Just like

----UserTable----

```
id  user    email       
1   admin   admin@gmail.com
2   editor  editor@gmail.com
```

----NameTable----

```
name    userid  fullname    mobile
own         1   Rahim       012314
father      1   Karim       120120
mother      1   Florin      212021
```

How to fetch data all (Just Like name, Father, Mother, Own name) data in single query in mysql?

Comment: You have to use multiple joins.

Comment: Any one give me a query for this? I am new, kindly give me a example query for this.

Answer (score 0):

Join to the name table once for each name:

```
select id, u.user, email, o.fullname own, f.fullname father, m.fullname mother
from users u
left join nametable o on o.userid = u.id and o.name = 'own'
left join nametable f on f.userid = u.id and f.name = 'father'
left join nametable m on m.userid = u.id and m.name = 'mother'
```

Note how all conditions on the name table must be in the join condition to allow the join to remain an outer join.